# How can I render an icon or empty selector if a pre-existing value exists in React-Phone-Input-2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, input, dropdown

Is there a way to render an icon or empty selector if a pre-existing value exists in [React-Phone-Input-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-input-2)?

```
<PhoneNumberInputField
   countryCodeEditable={ false }
   country={ defaultCountry() }
   value={ value }
   specialLabel={ translate('profile:profile.phone') }
   onChange={ (phoneNumber, data) => handlePhoneChange(phoneNumber, data) }
/>
```

Right now the first country flag si render in the selector: [image]

And I want something like this if the value exists and no country code is selected: [image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**New**
When we a default value, focused class disappeared therefore it don't show value. I added this to add `focused` class.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector('.phone-number-field')?.classList.add('focused');
  }, []);
```

**Old:**
For me this worked `autoFocus:true` and `onFocus` event worked

```
<PhoneNumberInputField
   countryCodeEditable={ false }
   country={ defaultCountry() }
   inputProps={{
        ... // otherprops
        autoFocus: value ? true : false,
      }}
   onFocus={() => {
        document.querySelector('.phone-number-field')?.classList.add('focused');
      }}
   specialLabel={ translate('profile:profile.phone') }
   onChange={ (phoneNumber, data) => handlePhoneChange(phoneNumber, data) }
/>
```

The issue is, it focus and show curor